# Using InfluxQL to count points (rows) with same value within an interval?

Tags: influxdb

I'm trying to leverage my moderate SQL-knowledge for InfluxQL, but I'm missing something(s) about the nature of timeseries db.

#### Use case

I write a measurements from our issue tracker, when an issue is updated:

`issue_updated,project=facebook,ticket=fb1,assignee=coolman status="todo"`

#### Problem

Given this returns rows of issues statuses:

```
SELECT status 
FROM  "issue_updated"
```

If this was SQL ([fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6595a/1)) I would use `COUNT`(and then add the `WHERE time > NOW() - 1Y GROUP BY time(5m)`). However the following gives me *Mixing aggregate and non-aggregate queries is not supported*

```
SELECT status, count(status) as 'Count'
FROM "issue_updated"
```

Can someone give some guidance here? ta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like what you're looking for is the ability to group by a field value which isn't currently supported.

From what I can tell, if you modify your schema a bit, it should be possible to do what you're looking. Instead of

```
issue_updated,project=facebook,ticket=fb1,assignee=coolman status="todo"
```

Do

```
issue_updated,project=facebook,ticket=fb1,assignee=coolman,status=todo value=1
```

then

```
SELECT count(value) FROM "issue_updated" WHERE time > now() - 52w GROUP BY status
name: issue_updated
tags: status=other
time            count
----            -----
1449523659065350722 1

name: issue_updated
tags: status=todo
time            count
----            -----
1449523659065350722 2
```

should work.

Comment: Unfortunately the same error _Mixing aggregate and non-aggregate queries is not supported_. It is something deeper I'm failing to understand (I guess I'm hoping to simply get a working example and work it out). https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.0/troubleshooting/errors/#error-parsing-query-mixing-aggregate-and-non-aggregate-queries-is-not-supported

Comment: Ah whoops. I totally made a mistake. You don't need the `status` in the select statement. I'll update my example

Comment: Yeah I did actually try that, but it returns no "rows"

Comment: Not sure I follow, can you explain a bit more.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Hm, selecting only the `count()` is something I thought I tried. I must be doing something else wrong - I'll drop the measurement and try again.

Comment: Let me know if you have any more questions. Happy to help as much as I can.